# A word for days you don't work

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there a word for days you don't work?

In portuguese you have the term "dias de folga" that means the days that you would normally work but will not because the company gave you those days to rest.

One is said in portugues to be in "folga".

Is there a correspondent word or term in english?

Comment: ***day off***- a day when you are not required to work.

Comment: When you say they gave you those days to rest.  I assume then you don't mean a regular occurrence like a weekend.  Are you talking about something like a holiday/vacation day?

Comment: If you plug "dias de folga" into online translators, they return *day off* as  Josh61 has suggested (e.g. *My manager gave me the day off*); *time off* is an alternative. Beyond that, you can always specify the type of day off— public holiday, sick leave, personal day, vacation, furlough, family leave, etc.

Comment: OK, but it is hard to trust these translations 100%, so I did not even try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few words and phrases used in English to describe days that you don't work.

The simplest, and most general phrase is "[day off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/day+off)".  A *day off* is any day you aren't working (generally, with the build-in assumption that normally you *would* be working that day).  For example:

- Sunday is my day off this week.
- I love this job, because I work Monday through Friday; the weekend is my days off.
- I was sick, so I took a day off.

To be more specific, in English we also have "vacation day" and "[sick day](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sick+day)":

- A *vacation day* is any day that you would have worked, but are taking a vacation.
- A *sick day* is any day that you would have worked, but are sick.

Comment: "days off" is perfect! THANKS!!!

Comment: In addition, you can refer to yourself and others as being "off" when you or they are not working. It is common to hear something like: "I'm off Thursday afternoon."